# Why WebView not working correctly when the text is longer than the width of the screen?

Tags: android, css, webview

Why WebView not working correctly when the text is longer than the width of the screen?

Code html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<div>
<img align="left" src="file:///android_res/drawable/asd.png"/> Hello   asdasdsdsadadsasdsdasdasdasdassda
 </div>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Java Android

```
        WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Is that a bug?

This is screen
http://pixs.ru/showimage/xJr0B1.jpg_1403285_16486028.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bug in webview.
You need to create your HTML page properly.

For confirmation you can try adding a space between the long word.

Here the long word is not fitting on right side of the image that's why it has moved below the image

Comment: Well, then, why this html works fine in Google Chrome on my PC? :)
Can still that you should include in WebView?

Comment: Because PC have large screen than the phone

Comment: But you are right(((. And what do I do then?Can you share the method or code?

Comment: I am not very good in HTML, you need make it responsive HTML file